# Why use prepared statements instead of Query / Exec with go sql package?

Tags: sql, go

In the go [`sql`](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package, I understand that each statement should be closed after execution.
Why would someone use prepared statements instead of just the raw `Query` or `Exec` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepared statement already bound to concrete connection to DB, contains low-level driver.Stmt and can be used concurrently by multiple go-routings. So it's quite handy to prepare and use, and things work faster.

Comment: I thought you can use prepared statement only once. Is it right?

Comment: @Robert Zaremba You can use prepared statement many times even concurrently. You usually defer stmt.Close(). You want explicitly close stmt only in transactions, which is special behaviour.

Comment: I thought I need to `Close` statement after usage to release the connection. So, then statements work after `Close`? IIUC - I can declare few "global" statements and use them all the time; after each usage I should `Close` and then I can use them again (even concurrently?).

Comment: You can't use closed stmt, this will return an error. You can use prepared stmt all the time and then close it when it not more needed. Closing stmt will free resources and return connection to connection pull. Tx is special case - stmt prepared in transaction belong to transaction and must be closed in Tx.

Comment: OK, so I shouldn't do _global_ statements and use them for the program life time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best answer comes from the wikipedia article on [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Quoting:

> The overhead of compiling and optimizing the statement is incurred
> only once, although the statement is executed multiple times. Not all
> optimization can be performed at the time the prepared statement is
> compiled, for two reasons: the best plan may depend on the specific
> values of the parameters, and the best plan may change as tables and
> indexes change over time.
>
> Prepared statements are resilient against SQL injection, because
> parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different
> protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement
> template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot
> occur.